# Using fivestar_get_votes() to show the votes on a node

Tags: rating

I need to display a multi-axis review system using Fivestar in node.tpl.php in Drupal 7.

I created the content type according to [this tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/457886), which is for Drupal 6, and I need to know how I can call `votingapi_select_results()` and `fivestar_theme()` in Drupal 7.

Initially, I tried the following code.

```
$design_rating = votingapi_select_results(array('entity_id' => $node->nid, 'tag' =>'design', 'function' => 'average'));
print_r($design_rating );
```

It caused a fatal error.

Later, I used `fivestar_get_votes()` as in the following code.

```
$design = fivestar_get_votes('node', $node->nid, 'design', NULL);
print_r($design);
```

I got an array.

```
  Array (
    [average] => Array (
      [vote_cache_id] => 128
      [entity_type] => node
      [entity_id] => 18
      [value] => 80
      [value_type] => percent
      [tag] => design
      [function] => average
      [timestamp] => 1332162918
    )
    [count] => Array(
      [vote_cache_id] => 127
      [entity_type] => node
      [entity_id] => 18
      [value] => 1
      [value_type] => percent
      [tag] => design
      [function] => count
      [timestamp] => 1332162918
    )
    [user] => Array(
      [vote_id] => 8
      [entity_type] => node
      [entity_id] => 18
      [value] => 80
      [value_type] => percent
      [tag] => design
      [uid] => 1
      [timestamp] => 1332162918
      [vote_source] => 122.164.241.37
      [function] => user
    )
  )
```

I don't know how to use it to show the result shown from the Fivestar module. How can I do it?

i tried with below code in node.tpl.php and it displayed result as '3' not a fivestar widget.

```
$variables=array('rating'=>60,'stars'=>5,'tag'=>'design');
echo theme('fivestar_static',$variables);
```

Am i missing anything in it? or is there any other procedure to call theme function in node.tpl.php in drupal 7?

Comment: You normally don't need to call `fivestar_theme()` as it is a hook implementation; if you really need to call that function, you just call it as any PHP function.

Comment: from memory, the only thing different between theme functions in drupal 6 and 7 is that 6 uses individual arguments while 7 uses an array for the arguments, so I'd imagine you would just call theme('fivestar_whatever', $args) instead of theme('fivestar_whatever', $a1, $a2, $a3 etc)

Answer (score 4):

Fivestar module for Drupal 7 implements fivestar as a field. Assuming the field name is `field_fivestar_awesomeness` you can print it anywhere with:

```
$fivestar = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_fivestar_awesomeness');
print render($fivestar);
```

There are some display and language options, see more in the [api docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7).

Comment: i created multiaxis rating system , so i am trying to bring the fivestar rating of another content type[review content type] into the parent content type[product content type].So how can i display it in parent content type node.tpl.php?

Comment: let's say you know the nid of the review node, load it and pass it to field_view_field. there is no secret here. in any case, the views module is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fivestar_custom_widget()` from the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module

1. Create rate from node

   ```
   $rating = votingapi_select_single_result_value(
    array(
       'entity_id' => $node->nid,
       'entity_type' => 'node',
       'tag' => 'vote',
       'function' => 'average',
   ));
   ```

2 Create form

```
$vote = drupal_get_form('fivestar_custom_widget', array('average'=>$rating), $settings);
```

where

```
$settings = array( 'stars' => 5, 'tag' => 'staff_vote');
```

see more in `fivestar.module`